Is there a way to select the video parts you want and automatically include the audio?
I was guessing if there is way to select only the video parts you want in ffmpeg but automatically include the audio for the selected parts without having to use aselect
ex:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select='between(t,20,30)+between(t,50,60)+between(t,80,90)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" -c:v libx265 -c:a aac "output.mp4"

Is there a easy way to include the audio for the selected parts without having to specify everything again with audio filter (-af) and aselect?

Have you reviewed the documentation? I'm guessing the answer is no. ffmpeg isn't magic, it is just very capable at doing what you tell it to, but you DO have to tell it.

I'm hoping there is some trick with async or something, I read the description about it but didn't fully understand it.

Can you share that description and explain what about it you did not understand?

@music2myear async descyption
For swr only, simple 1 parameter audio sync to timestamps using stretching, squeezing, filling and trimming. Setting this to 1 will enable filling and trimming, larger values represent the maximum amount in samples that the data may be stretched or squeezed for each second. Default value is 0, thus no compensation is applied to make the samples match the audio timestamps.
I got that setting it to 1 should ajust to timestamps but  I didn't get it to work....

No, you will have to use aselect.

@Gyan would be an interesting option to add in the future than, something like -audiosvs 1 (Audio Same as Video Selection) so you don't have to type so much code...

try multiple input with -ss -to and concat → ffmpeg -ss 20 -to 30 -i in.mp4 -ss 50 -to 60 -i in.mp4 ... -lavfi "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]...concat=...
